# Forwarding ServiceStack requests to other service handlers

Tags: .net, servicestack

I have a requirement to have one service handle a request, transform it to some other request, pass that request to the inner service, get the response, and transform it back to the outer service response. Some code may explain it better. This is what I have done:

```
public class InviteUserService : Service, IPost<Invitee>
{
    public RegistrationService RegistrationService { get; set; }

    public object Post(Invitee invitee)
    {
        // Do other invitation related work that is part of my domain.

        var registration = invitee.TranslateTo<Registration>();
        registration.UserName = invitee.EmailAddress;
        registration.Email = invitee.EmailAddress;

        // It previously threw a null ref exception until I added this.
        RegistrationService.RequestContext = RequestContext;

        var response = RegistrationService.Post(registration);
        if (response is RegistrationResponse)
        {
            var inviteeResponse = response.TranslateTo<InviteeResponse>();
            return inviteeResponse;
        }
        // Else it is probably an error and just return it directly to be handled by SS.
        return response;
    }
}
```

As the comment in the code above shows, before I passed down the `RequestContext` it was failing with a NullReferenceException. Now that I have done that it does work, but I'm wondering if I'm heading into an upstream battle in regards to how ServiceStack works? Will it cause me more problems down the track?

If both services were under my control, I would simply move the registration code into a separate shared dependency. However `RegistrationService` is built into ServiceStack, and doesn't seem to be callable in any other way apart from this. Unless I am missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to delegate requests to other services in [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) is to call `base.ResolveService<T>` which just [resolves the Service from the IOC and injects the current RequestContext](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Service.cs#L39-L45) for you. This is essentially similar to what you're doing but as this is the official API to do this, it will be maintained if anything else needs to be done.

Using this API your service would look like:

```
public class InviteUserService : Service, IPost<Invitee>
{
    public object Post(Invitee invitee)
    {
        // Do other invitation related work that is part of my domain.

        var registration = invitee.TranslateTo<Registration>();
        registration.UserName = invitee.EmailAddress;
        registration.Email = invitee.EmailAddress;

        // Resolve auto-wired RegistrationService from IOC
        using (var regService = base.ResolveService<RegistrationService>())
        {
            var response = regService.Post(registration);
            if (response is RegistrationResponse)
            {
                var inviteeResponse = response.TranslateTo<InviteeResponse>();
                return inviteeResponse;
            }
            return response;
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. And it turns out this is what the `RegistrationService` also does for auto logins to forward onto the `AuthService`, not sure how I missed that earlier...