# Creating new ServiceStack users via the RegistrationService within an existing user's session

Tags: .net, servicestack

This requirement has come up due to an invitation feature where an existing '**inviter** user' invites a new '**invitee** user' (it is different to a normal email invitation system as the inviter must set certain roles on the invitee's account, so the account must exist before the invitee reads the email and follows the link).

So following on from my previous question regarding [calling the RegistrationService from my InvitationService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702510/forwarding-servicestack-requests-to-other-service-handlers), I've got the message forwarding aspect working. But now the `RegistrationService` seems to [make an assumption that you are either creating a new user for the current session, or updating the current session's user details](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/RegistrationService.cs#L115-L118).

This causes an issue for my invitation service, as rather than creating a new invitee user the inviter's `UserAuth` is updated with the invitee's details.

Now I can create a new `InviteeRegistrationService`, which will basically do exactly the same as `RegistrationService` except for that existing user check (well it will probably still do the existing user check but return an 'already invited' response instead), but I don't really want to duplicate all that registration code and maintain the duplicate.

Is there any tricks/workarounds for this edge case? Or an actual feature that allows me to do this that I have missed?

Comment: Did you manage to create this InviteeRegistrationService class? It's very useful, so why not making a pull request with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [ServiceStack is all open source](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack), if you have special requirements, you're better off just taking a copy of the existing code and modify it to suit your needs. This is better than trying to abstract the RegistrationService so it tries to meet everyone's requirements, which in-turn makes it harder to read and understand for everyone.

Don't worry about code-duplication, as you have different requirements - start with the code from the RegistrationService as a template and change to suit your needs.

Comment: Thought this much, just wanted to make sure. Thanks again Demis, great framework you've developed here, I'm thoroughly enjoying learning all about it and working with it. And hopefully I'll be able to contribute back once I'm more up to speed with it and have finished my first project with it.